# Amazon AutoScaling Scale in removes instance like FIFO manner

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, autoscaling

Currently I am using amazon auto scaling service. I have observed that when there is scale in it removes firstly created instance. My problem is I also want to put RabbitMQ in auto scaling, and if i configure first instance as master instance then when there is scale in it removes master rabbitmq instance. I want to know that is there any way to give pattern of scale in for removing instance on Amazon EC2 auto scaling policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to leave your master RabbitMQ instance out of the auto-scaling cluster. and launch a secondary instance and have that auto-scale....  Remember to add both the Master Instance and the auto-scaling cluster to the load-balancer.

Comment: But how load can be distribute across the RabbitMQ cluster when new server add in cluster

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your english